# Ignoring a return-by-reference result from a function

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, return-by-reference

Suppose i have a function that returns an important result and several unimportant results. I declared it so that the unimportant results are returned by reference:

```
int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2, int& result1, int& result2);
```

I would like to call this function to calculate some stuff, but at call site i want to ignore the unimportant results. I could do it as follows:

```
...
int dummy1, dummy2;
int result = CalculateStuff(100, 42, dummy1, dummy2);
... // do something with the result
```

I would like to consider another way to do the same without declaring dummy variables:

```
int result = CalculateStuff(100, 42, *new int, *new int);
```

This has a memory leak (unacceptable), but has an advantage of showing my intent (ignoring the results) more clearly than the "dummy" names.

So, what would happen if i wrote it as follows:

```
int result = CalculateStuff(100, 42, auto_ptr(new int).get(), auto_ptr(new int).get());
```

Is it legal? Will the temporary integers still exist when the function's code is executed? Should i use `unique_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr`?

(Please don't suggest refactoring my code; i probably will - but first i want to understand how this stuff works)

Comment: Added as a comment as it doesn't actually answer your question - but I usually declare a temporary called _ and pass that if this comes up. "CalculateStuff(100, 42, _, _); seems reasonably clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is legal; `auto_ptr` objects will remain alive until the end of expression (i.e. function call). But it is ugly as hell.

Just overload your function:

```
int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2, int& result1, int& result2);
int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2) { 
    int r1=0, r2=0; 
    return CalculateStuff(param1, param2, r1, r2);
}
```

Comment: That still begs the *same* question, how are you going to implement the second overload? Are you going to use dummy variables, or `*new int` or `auto_ptr`, or what, so that you could call the first overload from the second?

Comment: @Nawaz for example, by creating two temporary variables, or calling some third implementation (e.g. the one with pointers that you suggested).

Comment: But that is exactly the question.

Answer (score 4):

According to Bjarne Stroustrup, if some parameters are optional, it is an ideal case for making them pointer type, so that you can pass `NULL` when you don't need to pass arguments for them:

```
int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2, int * result1, int * result2);
```

And use:

```
int result = CalculateStuff(100, 42, NULL, NULL);
```

All other alternatives would not be as good as this one, or at least not *better* than this.

Of course, the implementation of `CalculateStuff` has to check the parameters if they're `NULL` or not.

Answer (score 3):

A recommended approach if you have control over the function would be: return a `std::tuple` (or `boost::tuple`) with all results or write an overload that doesn't need the extra variables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my advice: if you have to ask on SO to figure out the correctness of the code and its semantics, then the code **fails at clearly expressing your intent**.

I think the first version (with `dummy1` and `dummy2`) is the most transparent, and is obviously correct.

If you find yourself repeatedly calling the function and not wanting the optional results, you could provide an overload:

```
int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2, int& result1, int& result2) {}

int CalculateStuff(int param1, int param2) {
  int unwanted1, unwanted2;
  return CalculateStuff(param1, param2, unwanted1, unwanted2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a class that provides implicit (or explicit) conversion to `int&`.

```
struct ignored
{
   int n;
   operator int&() { return n; }
};

n = CalculateStuff(a, b, ignored(), ignored());
```

You can further make this a template and add const overloads.

Comment: won't the type of ignored be const and give you trouble?

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Why? A temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference directly. However, one can call non-const methods of a temporary object. That's what this is taking advantage of.

Answer (score 2):

It's legal, but it's not guaranteed not to leak memory, see question 3
[here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm) for example.

The correct and idiomatic way of implementing optional output is to pass
a pointer, passing `NULL` when you don't want the results, and testing
for `NULL` in the function before writing through the pointer.